# expecting colon before rightparen and expecting identifier before if

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder

Another probably dumb question.
I followed a tutorial (popping game by Richard Parnaby-King).

i got this anoying errors that i cant seems to fix.

the main.as (called test1):

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip; 
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.utils.Timer;

[SWF(width='800',height='600',backgroundColor='#FFFFFF',frameRate='25')]

public class Test1 extends MovieClip
{

     var icon:FacebookIcon = new FacebookIcon();
     var background:BG = new BG();

     private var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000,-1);
     private var bubbles:Array = [];
     private var score:int;
     private var textBox:TextField = new TextField;
     private var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(null, 30);

    public function Test1(); void
    {   

        if(stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    }
    private function init(Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point

        //add start button
        icon.addChild(new StartButton());
        icon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        icon.buttonMode = true;
        icon.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (icon.width / 2);
        icon.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (icon.height / 2);
        addChild(icon);


        textBox.defaultTextFormat = textFormat; 

        private function startGame(e:MouseEvent):void {
                 icon.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
                 removeChild(icon);
                 removeChild(background);
                 timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, createBubble);
                 timer.start();
                 createBubble();
                 score = 0;
        }
```

I get the errors
 *1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before if*

and

*-1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before rightparen*

right where the

```
if(stage) init();
else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
```

What Im doing wrong? tried everything.
thanks a lot

Comment: Well for one your missing closing curly brackets on your class and package and init method - is that just a copy and paste error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a semi-colon before the return type on your constructor. It should be a colon:

```
public function Test1(): void
{   

    if(stage) init();
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

}
```

Comment: @Net.Uk.Sweet.. Yeah but what about those missing curly braces?? I didn't know we could get away with _that_ kind of shizzle, I mean, code!!. Shouldn't it be: `else { addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init); }` and so forth

Comment: exactly now i'm getting *Label must be a simple identifier.* in     new var icon:FacebookIcon = new FacebookIcon;
  new var bg:BG = new BG;

Comment: @VC.One - that's a perfectly legitimate if else statement in ActionScript 3.0 and JavaScript. Try it in the console in Chrome's dev tools.

Comment: Error in either the Facebook or BG classes? I think the rest of the code you've posted looks okay.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet.. You're right. I just tried it and AS3 _did_ let me get away with that syntax!!. Learning new tricks everyday. Though I still prefer curly braces, especially for complicated/nested loops. Easier to see where one thing ends and another begins..

Comment: @user3730098.. I think that name "icon" is clashing with something else built-into AS3. It should have changed colour (blue?) when you wrote it which means you better use an alternative name. Try `var _icon:FacebookIcon = new FacebookIcon();`